# web.config :: redirect all except root/index.html (Azure, WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, azure, redirect, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a Wordpress hosted on azure, that I have move from www.mydomain.com to old.mydomain.com,

on www.mydomain.com I make a new landing page that inform of what I want to inform and give a link to the "old" wordpress,

to avoid loosing seo (and keep wp info alive) I made the next web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://old.mydomain.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" /> 
    </system.webServer>

    <location path="www.mydomain.com">
       <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

</configuration>
```

redirect works perfectly, but it also redirect me www.mydomain.com to old.mydomain.com

**How can I do it in web.config this no-redirect-the-root ??**

I have try also the :

```
<location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

but the result is the same, everything gets redirect to old.mydomain.com

Comment: sorry to disturb, no one seems to know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `Rewrite module` of IIS, please consider the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Root rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
Your help was a light in the tunnel   ;-)